# how to add two integer values in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have written the following code

```
NSString *a = @"TextField1.text";
NSInteger b = [a integerValue];
NSString *p = @"TextField2.text";
NSInteger q = [p integerValue];
_TextLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", b+q];
```

its not adding up b and q always shows the result 0 in `_TextLable.text`

Comment: not a valid question in android section, ask at objective c stackoverflow

Comment: I was browsing java-tagged Qs when I bumped into this. I should learn objective-C first.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do in this code

Comment: yes its of objective c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSString *a = @"TextField1.text";` will give you an `NSString` with the following content:

```
TextField1.text
```

This certainly is not what you want.
The problem is, converting that to an Integer fails, and that's why the `NSInteger` is 0.
And since 0 * 2 stays 0, you get 0 as the result.

If you already have `TextField1` and `TextField2` as linked UITextFields, then use the following:

```
NSString *a = TextField1.text;
NSInteger b = [a integerValue];
NSString *p = TextField2.text;
NSInteger q = [p integerValue];
_TextLable.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", b+q];
```

I'd recommend reading a book on Objective C or programming in general, as it seems you lack basic understanding.

Comment: TextField1.text and TextField2.text has an value with string format i want convert it into integer an then add them

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSString *a = TextField1.text;
int b = [a integerValue];
NSString *p = TextField2.text;
int q = [p integerValue];
_TextLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", b+q];
```

Note : Please read some programming guides about objective-c and start coding